# Get only the commits that contributed to the changes in `git diff A...B`

Tags: git

I want to compare the differences between two branches at two specific commit points, and the all the commits that contributed to these differences. For example, let's consider the [tokio](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio) repository. I want to compare the differences between version `1.9.0` (commit `b280c6d` at `1.9.x` branch) and version `1.8.4` (commit `2273eb1` at `1.8.x` branch). When I do `git diff 2273eb1 b280c6d`, I can see the changes in code between the two commit points. My goal is to list all the commits that contributed to these changes (diff).

To achieve this goal, I did `git log --pretty=%H 2273eb1...b280c6d` which returns me 53 commits, 34 commits on the 1.9.x branch and 19 commits on the `1.8.x` branch. However, the problem is that the 1.8.x branch was merged into `1.9.x` twice since their oldest common ancestor. These two merge commits are present within the 34 commits coming from `1.9.x` branch, and therefore represents code changes present both in version `1.9.0` and `1.8.4` (therefore, not part of the `diff` between them). My goal is to detect these two commits and not count them, or in other words, get only the 51 commits that contributed to the code changes between the two version. How can I achieve this?

Note that, I tried another approach `git log --pretty=%H --ancestry-path 2273eb1...b280c6d`, which returns 28 commits, 9 from the `1.9.x` branch and 19 from `1.8.x` branch. However, this command cuts the commits from `1.9.x` branch at the two versions' latest common ancestor, and therefore, missed some prior commits that went into `1.9.x` branch (and results in the difference between `1.9.0` and `1.8.4`.)

Comment: In one sense, the problem is unsolveable; in one sense, it's trivial; if you define it carefully enough, it will be solveable, perhaps in a way useful to you. The issue here is that *every one of those 53 commits contributed*, it's just that some of them contributed something that's already in another commit, and perhaps some of them contributed something that got specifically *undone* by a later commit.

Comment: Merge commits in particular cause all the "contributions" of a branch (since the common merge base commit) to appear courtesy of the merge commit itself. So the merge commit could, in theory, be removed—except that its contribution to the *history* is essential, so it cannot be removed; so the other commits could be removed instead, but in a sense, they are the "true source" of the contribution.

Comment: This is why you'll have to reformulate your problem. What, precisely, do you want? Do you want the actual history, in which case you need all the commits? Do you want to know which commits *first* made a contribution, in which case you can discard merges? Do you want to eliminate any commit whose contribution was later undone by a reversion? In this case you must apply some post-processing computation, and you might end up needing to "split" a commit where it contributed 3 changes, 2 of which were reverted but 1 of which was retained.

Comment: Given how you've written the text of your question, it sounds like you might just want `--no-merges`. That's the easy way to have `git log` discard the merge commits themselves. Be aware, however, that if any one of the merges specifically undoes a change (through conflict resolution) or is an "evil merge", this will produce something that might be misleading.

Comment: the problem with `--no-merges` is that if there's a commit that merged commits from another branch other than `1.8.x`, e.g. `1.7.x`, to `1.9.x`, I would have to keep that commit. Thank you for your explanation. I will try to reformulate the problem based on what I want. For now, I know that I do not want the two commits mentioned in the question, but need better formulation. @torek